# C Programming on command line

Tags: command-line, vim, compiling, c

What to do after opening vim name.c and writing the source code? I mean, to compile and execute.

Comment: rather trivial, simple search for *"how to compile a program on Linux"* with an internet search service gives plenty of results,

Comment: But those are all in GUI. Not command line.

Comment: Search again, resources are plentiful. It took me 5 seconds to find: http://luv.asn.au/overheads/compile.html. You probably also want to read some introductory tutorial to using UNIX command line, if *"that is in GUI"* is an issue.

Comment: you can search like _c programming on linux command line_

Answer (score 5):

Open or make a new file by:

```
vim name.c
```

then write the C program you intend then save and exit by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> then `:wq`.
Then compile it as:

```
gcc name.c -o name
```

then run it as:

```
./name
```

[More](http://www.linfo.org/create_c1.html)

Comment: Where do these files go? I mean the save directory.

Comment: @FahimFerdous  by default your terminal starts in your home directory `/home/username`

Comment: I believe that you should remove the occurrences of `.o` from your answer.

Comment: The .o extension is for object files, which are compiled but not linked (`gcc -C`, I believe). Your command compiles and links, so just use `-o name`

Comment: can you give me a link for these commands?

Comment: @FahimFerdous you dont need command links, open your terminal and type `man gcc` for details on gcc, `man vim` for vim etc. also you should probably learn basics of [bash shell and commands](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/basic.html) like `cd`, `ls`, `pwd`, `nano` and `mkdir` etc

Answer (score 2):

An alternative (after creating `name.c`) is to type

```
make name
```

This will automatically invoke the `gcc` command shown in edward’s answer
(or maybe some variant on it,
such as `gcc -o name name.c`
or possibly `cc name.c -o name`). 
This has the trivial advantage
of being about ten or twelve fewer characters to type. 
It has the more substantial advantage that,
if you develop a serious program with multiple source files,
you can write a `Makefile` that describes the relationships and interdependencies among those files, and you will still be able
to compile the program by typing `make name`,
even if that needs to invoke many compile commands.